# How to pronounce "users' email"?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation, possessives

Minutes ago, I was reading an article "Yahoo, Google and Apple also claim rights to read user emails". As usual I was reading it out loud, and I was stuck at "Following the revelation that Microsoft could, and did, read users' email".

How should I pronounce it, should I just read it as if it were "user's email" or should I pronounce it like [juzerziz]?

Comment: It is unclear what the alternatives are. What does [juzerziz] correspond to and why would you imagine that that is the pornunciation of "user's email"? Are you contrasting "user emails" and "user's email"?

Comment: You seem to be trying to treat the root word "user" as an irregularly declined noun which ends in an "S". It's not, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pronounce it like "user's email."

Comment: Can anyone imagine the uproar there would be if the Royal Mail, or the US Mail, started steaming open people's envelopes and reading the contents?

Comment: @WS2: Whatever next! If we let them get away with reading our dead tree mails, who knows - they might start reading our emails and listening to our phone conversations!